# How do I check if an element is in the DOM using a jquery deferred object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, deferred

I'm wondering if it is possible to use a jQuery deferred object to test whether or not an element is in the DOM.

Here's kind of what I'm thinking:

```
function chkDOM(selector) {
  if $(selector) {
    return deferred.promise();
  }
}

$.when(chkDOM(selector)).then(function() {
  // do something
});
```

I don't exactly know how to form the code to make this happen, but I hope that my question makes sense. If I can get this piece to work right, then I can essentially delay the calling of certain jquery plugins so that they actually run properly.

Thanks!

Comment: This looks wrong `if $(selector) {`... Why using a deferred? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Deferreds are to do with responding to the progress and completion asynchronous tasks, but I don't perceive any asynchronicity in the scenario described above.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I missed one key piece, the problem is the DOM element gets injected asynchronously. Appreciate the answer "Explosion Pills" :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume that you are running a loop that periodically checks the existence of the selector:

```
var dfd = $.Deferred();
var checkSelector = setInterval(function () {
    if ($("#selector").length) {
        dfd.resolve();
        clearInterval(checkSelector);
    }
}, 1000);

dfd.done(function () {
   console.log('it has been added');
});
```

Note that `$.when` is not needed; you can just use `.done` on the deferred object directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to check if an element exists.
You don't have to use deferred.

```
if( jQuery(selector).length > 0 ) {
    // exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check element in DOM, just use

```
if($(selector).length > 0) {
// do something

}
```

$(selector) return an array of elements that match the condition of selector.